# Predict number of days to collect cash

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, forecasting, predictive-models

I need to predict number of days past due date to collect cash for a product based company which sells their product to more than 5000 clients. We receive ~100K invoices on weekly basis and the prediction needed at the invoice level.
The predictors would be invoice amount, client information (like demographics, finances, etc.) and their historical payment behavior.

Which statistical technique would be best fit in this scenario and why?

Comment: Have you considered a proportional hazards model?

Comment: No, I have not. What's that?

Comment: See @peterflom's answer

Comment: To get started with survival analysis I suggest you take a look at [UCLA](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/). They have examples in different programming languages and are pretty easy to follow.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's time to event, you want survival analysis.  Because you have both invoice level and person level data, you want a multilevel analysis. Fortunately, such models do exist.

E.g see [Yau](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2676846?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), *Multilevel Models for Survival Models with Random Effects* in *Biometrics*, vol 57, p 96-102.

There are ways to model these in [SAS](http://www.lexjansen.com/pharmasug/2003/StatisticsPharmacokinetics/sp049.pdf), R (coxme package) and [Stata](http://www.stata.com/new-in-stata/multilevel-survival-models/)

Comment: Addition to the R suggestion: another option is the frailtypack package. Even the survival package has a function to include a frailty term in your survival model.